# Django static files won't load

Tags: python, django, static, django-static

i'm a Django newbie working on my first project and having a problem with static files.

I have created a simple auth system using `django.contrib.auth` consisting of two templates: `mysite/templates/index.html` and `mysite/templates/registration/login.html`.  I have global static content in `mysite/static` which I want to be able to access on all templates rendered by all apps.

`mysite/templates/index.html` contains `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}pics03.jpg"/>` which renders as `"static/pics03.jpg"` and loads fine when I visit the url `localhost:8000/`

`mysite/templates/registration/login.html` contains `<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}pics03.jpg"/>` which also renders as `"static/pics03.jpg"` and does not load when I visit the url `"localhost:8000/accounts/login/"`

In my urls.py I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home'), # plays index.html template
   url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

In my settings.py I have:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static'),
)  

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

I was under the impression that Django should be looking for global static content in STATICFILES_DIRS, but it doesn't find the static content for login.html even if I change the url in there to an absolute path to the static folder.  Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your problem is that you arent listening to the URL "/static/" nowhere in your urls.py

If you serve your application via a webserver like apache or nginx then this is normal as the webserver would handle the static files itself.

For development Django comes with a built-in static server

to urls.py, at the very end add

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

What this does is to add the /static/ url and let you serve those without a webserver.

This is equivalent to

```
url(
    regex=r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 
    view='django.views.static.serve', 
    kwargs={'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,}
)
```

some people will tell you that you need to wrap the URL-rules in a "if settings.DEBUG" to use the dev-only rules, but this isnt needed at all and actually i find that to be a bad advice.

Comment: Well, actually on the latter case it is necessary to wrap that rule. If you take a look at django's code you'll see that the view doesn't do any checking for DEBUG.

Comment: The view is never hit because your webserver is set up to catch those and serve static files, so no check needed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you having trouble when using the build in runserver or are you serving using Apache or similar? I've struggled with this a bit. The documentation I follow is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/

The second part is key when you are ready to deploy. You need to define a static root (which will be empty to begin with) and run the `manage.py collectstatic` command to move the static files from throughout your project into that folder. Then you can serve them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Does changing `STATIC_ROOT=''` to `STATIC_ROOT='/'` help?

It seems to me the only difference is that `static/pics03.jpg` (relative path) exists on the home page, but doesn't on the other.

The absolute path `/static/pics03.jpg` exists in both cases.  If changing `STATIC_ROOT` doesn't help, just add a `/` to the beginning of the urls.