# Not serving staticfiles default behavior when running `gunicorn_django`?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, static-files

`myproject_django$ gunicorn_django` serves my site except for the static files. Any Idea why? I am running this from a virtual environment using django 1.3.

**Project tree**

```
myproject_django
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── base.css
│   │   ├── layout.css
│   │   └── skeleton.css
│   └── media
│       ├── pek.ico
│       ├── pek.png
│       └── pek_symbol.png
├── templates
│   └── core
│       ├── 404.html
│       ├── 500.html
│       ├── home.html
│       └── install.html
├── urls.py
```

**Potentially relevent parts of settings.py**

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = '/static/media'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'gunicorn',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to configure nginx or apache to handle the static files. For now try running python manage.py collectstatic and add the below code to urls.py

`urls.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^static/media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
        )
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
                 (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
            )
```

Comment: When I run `$ python manage.py collectstatic` I get this error:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting`. I then set `STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH` in `settings.py`. Then it didn't give any errors but when running `$ gunicorn_django` I still don't see the static files.

Comment: Create a directory called `project_static` and update `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'project_static'),
)
`

Comment: So I created `project_static` inside `myproject_django`. Then I placed the `css` and `media` directories inside `project_static` (basically renamed my `static` directory to `project_static`). Then I implemented `STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'project_static'), )` in `settings.py` (next to `STATIC_ROOT = PROJECT_PATH`). Then I ran `python manage.py collectstatic` again and then `gunicorn_django`. I still don't see the static files displayed.

Comment: Did you change `urls.py` to what I stated above and set `DEBUG=True` in `settings.py` ?

Comment: I forgot to change `DEBUG` to `True`. Now it properly serves my css! Yay! But still not my images. If this is the ONLY way to serve static files with gunicorn alone (needing to change `DEBUG` to `true`) that basically means that I should not use this setting in a production environment.

Comment: Well you could move the `urlpatterns` logic outside the `debug=true` and it would work in production. But its not recommended. Images should work too, hope you have `PIL` installed and just try debugging the paths.

Comment: It works now! I just had to change my `MEDIA_ROOT` to `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'project_static/media')`. Thank you!

Comment: I suspected this was not the best approach. I [quote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216827/django-static-files-wont-load) the user `krs`: "Some people will tell you that you need to wrap the URL-rules in a "if settings.DEBUG" to use the dev-only rules, but this isnt needed at all and actually i find that to be a bad advice."

Comment: I don't agree to that. While it simplifies a lot of things while starting, using django's static file serve is not suited for production. Using a CDN or configuring Nginx to do so is the best way. So when people are ready to go beyond development, this should break and people should fix it the right way.

Comment: @PratikMandrekar I think Bentley4's comment was based on Django's staticfiles view behavior: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) it only works when DEBUG=True so wrapping with "if settings.DEBUG:" really isn't necessary. It *will* fail when DEBUG!=True.

Comment: Agree. Just wanted to highlight that it should not be used when `DEBUG=False`