# Django Media Upload Settings and File Structure

Tags: python, django, upload, settings, media

Here is how I have configured my `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` settings in my django 1.4 project:

```
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) ## from http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/02/11/django-settings-tip-setting-relative-paths/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media') ## from http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/02/11/django-settings-tip-setting-relative-paths/
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static')
```

My directory structure is like this:

```
--myproject
----myapp
----media  ## where I expect the images
----myproject   ##(settings.py, urls.py, etc.)
```

But the images are being saved to another directory inside the `myproject` folder:

```
--myproject
----myapp
----media
----myproject
------media  ## this is where the files end up
```

As a result the files aren't being included. Here are the urls:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()  ## from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216827/django-static-files-wont-load

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}))
```

How can I fix my configuration so that user uploaded media files will appear? Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do it would be to just change

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media')
```

to

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'media')
```

since `SITE_ROOT` is set to the directory where your `settings.py` file lives, which seems to be `myproject/myproject`.