# django won't find static files in development

Tags: python, django

I have a project with this structure

```
myproject
    ├── myproject
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── settings.pyc
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   └── wsgi.pyc
    ├── manage.py
    ├── showcase
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── urls.pyc
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── views.pyc
    ├── static
    │   └── images
    │       ├── pics01.jpg
    │       └── pics11.jpg
    └── templates
        └── showcase
            └── base.html
```

In `settings.py` I've declared:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and by connecting to `127.0.0.1/static/images/pics01.jpg` I get a 404 error

> 'images/pics01.jpg' could not be found

Why is this?

`urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()` is already in the project `urls.py` as I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216827/django-static-files-wont-load) question.

Comment: What is your STATICFILES_DIRS setting?

Comment: Turn on debug with `DEBUG=True` and show us the error you get there?
Also, how are you serving the static files, as Django doesn't do this by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) setting:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```